# Using Servlets 3 in IBM RAD 8?

Tags: websphere, servlet-3.0, ibm-rad

I've been asked to get a web application running in WebSphere using RAD 8.0.1, which isn't my usual app.server or development environment.

I'm starting off simple, using the default Ajax Test Server, but from what I can see, the default for a Dynamic Web Application is Servlets 2.5. Is there something buried in the twisty little maze of config dialogs to set it to Servlets 3.0, or must I handle that manually?

Answer (score 3):

IBM Websphere Application Server 8.0 supports Servlet 3.0

IBM Websphere Application Server versions 7.0 and 6.1 do not support it.
So you need to use version 8.0. If you are using Websphere Portal, then you have a problem.

IBM Websphere Portal runs on same version Application Server (though you can for instance run Portal 6.1 on WAS 7 - I ran into some problems with AJAX though). So you might be able to get Portal 7 to run on WAS 8. It's the only way in the short term.

Answer (score 2):

What is the run-time environment that you use?

WebSphere 7.x does not support Servlets 3.0 and it would be supported only by WebSphere 8.0.

WebSphere 8.0 is still in beta.

Interestingly, wikipedia is a good site for the list of supported APIs by WAS.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_WebSphere_Application_Server

I don't have a RAD 8 handy with me to assist but i would check and ensure that the run-time associated with the project does support Java EE 6 (and Servlets 3.0)

HTH
Manglu

Answer (score 0):

Websphere Application Server 7 can support servlets 3.0 if you installed [Fix Pack 7.0.0.37](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24039338) or later.
That shall upgrade JDK from 1.5.x to 1.6.x. Also you need to install [WebSphere Application Server V7 Feature Pack for Web 2.0 and Mobile V1.1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24035227)